# Is Windows window creation faster / more efficient than GLFW window creation?

Tags: opengl, c++, windows, vulkan

Are there any benefits to using Windows window for OpenGL or Vulkan rendering, rather than using GLFW window?

Is there any performance hits when using C++ Window creation over GLFW since it provides OpenGL and Vulkan interface?

Comment: It's worth noting that, even though I haven't checked the source, libraries like `GLFW` are used primarily to support multiple platforms, and on windows it is likely using the same function behind the scenes to open a new window. So there shouldn't be any noticeable performance difference.

Comment: This does not look like a source of concern, unless you plan on creating too many windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It depends**

GLFW is just a wrapper around the Windows API calls, so whether you create a window using GLFW or create one using the API, the same calls are ultimately being made.

However, a wrapper such as GLFW can be expected to be robust, to do error-checking, to select optimal formats, and so on, which you may not do if you just wrote the code yourself.  So your own code *may* be faster at creating a window, but it *may* also be more likely to do the wrong thing.

At this stage you really need to read the [OpenGL wiki Getting Started](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Getting_Started) pages to gain an understanding of the process of initializing OpenGL.

But ultimately, what does it matter?  Creating a window is milliseconds at the beginning of your application, and once the window is created OpenGL takes over, so it does not matter how it was created - all other things being equal (pixel formats, hardware acceleration, etc) the performance of OpenGL in your program will be identical.